# Intermittent Run-Time Error when extracting slides from one PowerPoint presentation to create a presentation

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, powerpoint

The following code sometimes on `newPresentation.Slides.Paste` shows an error when my sourcePresentation has the slide.

> Clipboard is empty or nothing to paste

I put in `On Error GoTo Repeat` assuming the code will repeat until there is no error and new presentation would be extracted.
Even then the run-time error pops up.
Another issue is that if the code works the first time, it still executes the Repeat and hence, closes the new presentation to run the code again.

```vb
Sub CreateNewPresentation()
    
    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Dim sourcePresentation As Object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set sourcePresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
    Dim newPresentation As Object
    Dim slideNumber As Integer
    Dim selectedSlides As Range
    Dim slideRange As String
 
    ' Set the range of selected slide numbers in column A (adjust the sheet name if needed)
    Set selectedSlides = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("B4:B70")
    
    ' Create a new presentation
    Set newPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
 
    On Error GoTo Repeat

    ' Loop through each selected slide number
    For Each cell In selectedSlides
        slideNumber = cell.Value
 
        ' Copy the slide to the new presentation
        sourcePresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Copy
        newPresentation.Slides.Paste    
            
    Next cell
    
Repeat:
     newPresentation.Close
 
    ' Create a new presentation
    Set newPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
 
    ' Loop through each selected slide number
    For Each cell In selectedSlides
        slideNumber = cell.Value
 
        ' Copy the slide to the new presentation
        sourcePresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Copy
        newPresentation.Slides.Paste
            
    Next cell
    
    ' Clean up the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: a) Is the ActivePresentation always the source presentation? b) Are you sure all cells in the range ("B4:B70") contain valid slide numbers *and* those slides are present?

Comment: Your code is running faster than the I/O operations of your computer. Search on _Wait_, _Sleep_ and _DoEvents_ for methods to slow down your VBA. Your existing Repeat loop is added more I/O events (closing the file, then creating another new one), so is making the problem worse. Instead you probably just need to add a delay between copying and pasting.